# Editing Local Windows Built in Group: Network Operator

Tags: windows, security-groups

We need our local Built-in Group Network operator to be able to modify the speed ( aka Advanced TCP-IP setting) of the Windows 10 Network adapter but as per our test/research, this privilege is not granted to this group per default.
Is there a way to modify this built-in group to allow access to the Advanced TCP/IP tab in order for them to change the speed?
Either in GUI or trough REGEDIT would be very acceptable solutions
Thanks in advance